# Plot z variable in R with conditional "size" argument

Tags: r, variables, plot, scatter-plot

I want to create a scatterplot in R with a third "z" variable that is plotted in differently sized dots according to their value range.

Here is the data frame `df` I have:

```
    mean.temp mean.lfk  LKZ
v3   24.33958 69.43333 12.5
v7   25.80208 67.76250 53.3
v8   26.24583 66.85000 12.5
v11  21.52917 42.59375 35.0
v13  23.96042 66.92917 20.0
v14  24.16042 66.74375 56.7
v15  26.88542 69.69583 10.0
v16  26.45417 72.37292 56.7
v17  24.92708 64.59375  6.7
v18  25.77391 65.64348  3.3
v21  23.11290 71.37419  0.5
```

I want to use `mean.temp` and `mean.lfk` along for the x and y axis but I do not want to actually plot their values. Instead, I want to plot `LKZ` as a "z" variable. The different values of `LKZ` shall be visualised by differently sized dots, i.e. `0.5` is the smallest dot and `56.7` is the biggest dot.

I did not get very far and managed to only get this piece of code which is clearly not working as you can see with the figure below:

```
plot(df$mean.temp, df$mean.lfk, pch = paste(df$LKZ))
```

[image]

Any idea on how to get what I want with R base graphics?

Comment: try `as.factor(df$LKZ)` rather than paste? Also ggplot is super good at this sort of thing. Also please include the output of `dput(data)` so we can help better

Comment: I added the figure as output from the plotting command. `as.factor(df$LKZ)` does not work as R responds with `Error in plot.xy(xy, type, ...) : invalid plotting symbol`. I did not work with ggplot yet, so I am happy about a base graphic solution.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The plotting argument `cex` controls the size of the character.  Since your sizes range by a factor of 100, in my example below I made the point size proportional to the square root of LKZ.  Also, the larger points obscure the smaller ones so I added some transparency to the points so that you could see them all.

```
plot(df[,1:2], pch=16, cex=sqrt(df$LKZ), col="#00000044",
    xlim=c(21,27), ylim=c(40,75))
```

[image: Size proportional to LKZ]

**Data**

```
df = read.table(text="    mean.temp mean.lfk  LKZ
v3   24.33958 69.43333 12.5
v7   25.80208 67.76250 53.3
v8   26.24583 66.85000 12.5
v11  21.52917 42.59375 35.0
v13  23.96042 66.92917 20.0
v14  24.16042 66.74375 56.7
v15  26.88542 69.69583 10.0
v16  26.45417 72.37292 56.7
v17  24.92708 64.59375  6.7
v18  25.77391 65.64348  3.3
v21  23.11290 71.37419  0.5", 
header=TRUE)
```

Answer (score 1):

Assuming you want to plot y = `mean.lfk` against x = `mean.temp` using a circle whose size indicates the value of `LKZ` use `cex=` to specify that size.

Now, using `df` shown reproducibly in the Note at the end try this (or alternately try `cex = log(LKZ)` ).

```
plot(mean.lfk ~ mean.temp, df, cex = LKZ/10)
```

[image: screenshot]

### Note

```
Lines <- "
    mean.temp mean.lfk  LKZ
v3   24.33958 69.43333 12.5
v7   25.80208 67.76250 53.3
v8   26.24583 66.85000 12.5
v11  21.52917 42.59375 35.0
v13  23.96042 66.92917 20.0
v14  24.16042 66.74375 56.7
v15  26.88542 69.69583 10.0
v16  26.45417 72.37292 56.7
v17  24.92708 64.59375  6.7
v18  25.77391 65.64348  3.3
v21  23.11290 71.37419  0.5"
df <- read.table(text = Lines)
```